How to achieve peak flop throughput for FMA when using input data (while maintaining the required roofline compute/load ratio)?
I try to achieve peak float throughput for SIMD FMA computations while loading input data. I load as much data as permitted by relative compute / memory load speeds. I also applied buffering to avoid immediate data dependencies, but this didn't help either. Unfortunately, the throughput is off by a factor of two.
Consider the following FMA function:
 std::pair<float, float> fmadd_256(const float* aptr, const float* bptr,
                                  uint64_t sz, uint32_t num_loads) {
    constexpr size_t num_lanes = 256 / (sizeof(float) * 8);
    __m256 c[8];
    __m256 a[2][num_loads];
    __m256 b[2][num_loads];
    load_buffer(aptr, bptr, a[0], b[0], 0);
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        uint64_t curr_buffer = i % 2;
        __m256* curra = a[curr_buffer];
        __m256* currb = b[curr_buffer];
        if (i < sz - 1) {
            uint64_t next_buffer = (i + 1) % 2;
            __m256* nexta = a[next_buffer];
            __m256* nextb = b[next_buffer];
            uint64_t load_position = (i + 1) * num_lanes * num_loads;
            load_buffer(aptr, bptr, nexta, nextb, load_position);
        }
        c[0] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[0]);
        c[1] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[1]);
        c[2] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[2]);
        c[3] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[3]);
        c[4] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[1], currb[1], c[4]);
        c[5] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[1], currb[1], c[5]);
        c[6] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[1], currb[1], c[6]);
        c[7] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[1], currb[1], c[7]);
    }
    constexpr size_t num_unrolls = 8;
    uint64_t flops{num_unrolls * num_lanes * 2 * sz};
    float res = epilogue(c);
    return {res, flops};
}

When running the code above, I get a GFLOPS/sec ratio of about 60, but my computer can achieve 130 GFLOPS/sec. When disabling memory loads, the code achieves 120 GFLOPS/sec. I used a Alderlake processor. According to Intel Advisor, the neccessary compute/memory load ratio to achieve peak throughput is 4.4 when taking the DRAM speed into consideration.
What could I do to improve the throughput of the program?
Interestingly, buffering does not improve the program's performance. When loading data into the used buffer (setting uint64_t next_buffer = i % 2), the code runs as fast as when I cycle over the two buffers. I could also used aligned vectors instead of unaligned vectors or rewrite the code to avoid the branch inside the loop, but I doubt that's the root cause for the relatively slow program.
The code is compiled with  gcc 11.4.0 and the flags are -O2 -march=alderlake -g -ffast-math -Wall -Wextra. I make sure to run the program on one core. Theoretically, I compute max GFLOPS of 4.9 GHZ * 2 FMA * 2 UNITS * 8 Lanes ~ 156GFLOPS/sec. Intel Advisor shows me a max compute throughput of roughly ~130GFLOPS/sec.
Edit based on the Comments
The compiler's behavior
As noted in the comments below and upon inspecting the code on godbolt, the compiler produces much work. For me, the greatest obstacles to efficient code are the large number of memory operations and the low diversity of registers.

I count 12 vmovups operations per loop iteration, but four seem sufficient.
The compiler uses few registers and, even more problematic, the same registers to load buffered data and hold source data for the FMA ops.

I would guess the main loop would be something like the following for the compiler:

Use registers 0-7 as destination registers for the FMA ops
When i %  2 == 0:

Prefetch data into registers 8-11
Use registers 12-15 as source registers for the FMA operation


When i % 2 == 1:

Prefetch data into registers 12-15
Use registers 8-11 as source registers



Attempts tried that didn't work
Based on the comments, I tried the following:

Removing the branch condition inside the loop by reducing the loop iterations by one iteration and lifting code before and after the loop
More aggressive optimizations (O3) and different compiler (clang 17.0.1)

Bugs in the original program
In the original program, I wrote num_lanes = 256 / sizeof(float); but it should be num_lanes = 256 / (sizeof(float) * 8);
Full Program
The full program for the test is below:
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>

#include <chrono>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

inline float hadd(__m256 v8) {
    __m128 v = _mm256_extractf128_ps(v8, 1);
    v = _mm_add_ps(v, _mm256_castps256_ps128(v8));
    v = _mm_add_ps(v, _mm_movehl_ps(v, v));
    v = _mm_add_ss(v, _mm_movehdup_ps(v));
    return _mm_cvtss_f32(v);
}

float epilogue(__m256 c[8]) {
    c[0] = _mm256_add_ps(c[0], c[1]);
    c[2] = _mm256_add_ps(c[2], c[3]);

    c[4] = _mm256_add_ps(c[4], c[5]);
    c[6] = _mm256_add_ps(c[6], c[7]);

    c[0] = _mm256_add_ps(c[0], c[3]);
    c[4] = _mm256_add_ps(c[4], c[6]);

    c[0] = _mm256_add_ps(c[0], c[4]);
    float res = hadd(c[0]);
    return res;
}

template <typename T>
void reporting(T duration, double flops, float res) {
    float gflops_sec = (flops * 1000.0) / duration;
    std::cout << "THe inner product is: " << res << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GFLOPS/sec: " << gflops_sec << std::endl;
    std::cout << "total gflops: " << flops << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << duration << std::endl;
}

void load_buffer(const float* aptr, const float* bptr, __m256* a, __m256* b,
                 uint64_t idx) {
    a[0] = _mm256_loadu_ps(aptr + idx);
    a[1] = _mm256_loadu_ps(aptr + idx + 8);
    b[0] = _mm256_loadu_ps(bptr + idx);
    b[1] = _mm256_loadu_ps(bptr + idx + 8);
}
std::pair<float, float> fmadd_256(const float* aptr, const float* bptr,
                                  uint64_t sz, uint32_t num_loads) {
    constexpr size_t num_lanes = 256 / (sizeof(float) * 8);
    __m256 c[8];
    __m256 a[2][num_loads];
    __m256 b[2][num_loads];
    load_buffer(aptr, bptr, a[0], b[0], 0);
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        uint64_t curr_buffer = i % 2;
        __m256* curra = a[curr_buffer];
        __m256* currb = b[curr_buffer];
        if (i < sz - 1) {
            uint64_t next_buffer = (i) % 2;
            __m256* nexta = a[next_buffer];
            __m256* nextb = b[next_buffer];
            uint64_t load_position = (i + 0) * num_lanes * num_loads;
            load_buffer(aptr, bptr, nexta, nextb, load_position);
        }
        c[0] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[0]);
        c[1] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[1]);
        c[2] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[2]);
        c[3] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[0], currb[0], c[3]);
        c[4] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[1], currb[1], c[4]);
        c[5] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[1], currb[1], c[5]);
        c[6] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[1], currb[1], c[6]);
        c[7] = _mm256_fmadd_ps(curra[1], currb[1], c[7]);
    }
    constexpr size_t num_unrolls = 8;
    uint64_t flops{num_unrolls * num_lanes * 2 * sz};
    float res = epilogue(c);
    return {res, flops};
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    constexpr uint64_t sz = {1000000};
    constexpr uint64_t num_loads = 2;
    constexpr uint64_t num_lanes = 256 / sizeof(float);
    constexpr uint64_t eles{num_loads * num_lanes * sz};
    std::vector<float> a(eles);
    std::vector<float> b(eles);
    double total_res{0};
    constexpr size_t RUNS{100};
    fmadd_256(a.data(), b.data(), sz, num_loads);  // test call
    uint64_t total_flops{0};
    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < RUNS; ++i) {
        auto [res, flops] = fmadd_256(a.data(), b.data(), sz, num_loads);
        total_flops += flops;
        total_res += res;
        std::swap(a, b);
    }
    double total_gflops = 1e-9 * (double)total_flops;
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double duration =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin)
            .count();
    reporting(duration, total_gflops, total_res);
}


What are the exact compilation flags used to compile the C++ code and the target compiler (including its version)?

Do you make your test on a big-core ("performance" core) or a little-core ("efficient" core) ? 120 GFlops is really low for big cores and it seems even rather small for an efficient core. Thus, I guess this is the computing power of only 1 core.

Thanks for the questions, @JérômeRichard. I edited the post.

__m256 a[2][num_loads]; doesn't compile for me, due to num_loads not being a constant

Anyway according to uiCA, the asm (as generated by GCC 11.4 with those compilation options) contains enough "junk" (I'm broadly categorizing anything that isn't an FMA instruction as "junk") to be a throughput problem on Rocket Lake, which I realize is not Alder Lake (but Alder Lake is not available yet on uiCA). Without considering memory throughput, the loop would run at most at 7 cycles per iteration instead of the 4 that it'd need to hit for max flops.

@user555045 How did you found that. I did the same thing on IceLake/RocketLake and I found 4.5-4.9 cycle or RCP which is pretty good since FMA units are 4.25/4.75 cycle per iteration. This is close to be optimal on such architecture. My try was based on this result (and more specifically the L18 loop -- I assume L17 was never taken). Sad AlderLake is not available yes :( .

@JérômeRichard the L8 loop all the way down to jmp .L8, ie including the inlined call to load_buffer (which happens almost every iteration)

@user555045 Oh I did not see this one. I wonder which loop is actually taken. Based on the code, L8 make more sense indeed.

I would remove the internal condition (so to reduce junk instructions) by splitting it in two parts : main loop and last remaining iterations. Then I would (manually) unroll it twice so to remove more junk instructions (like the modulo 2).

Thanks will try that, @JérômeRichard. I had the same thoughts with in my suggested lists of improvements. I'm not sure this will change much, but will try and report above!

Thanks for the comments so far, @JérômeRichard and user555045. I added some questions and comments based on further research I did due to your comments. So far, I couldn't improve the runtime though.

"I count 12 vmovups operations per loop iteration" where do you see that? I see only 4 of them. 12 in the whole asm code but the one in the load_buffer function are never executed since the function is never called in the code (you should make it static so to remove this dead code by the way -- the compiler do not know if the function is called from outside). The 4 others are only executed one when entering the function.

"the same registers to load buffered data" This is not always a problem : modern CPUs can rename registers. The only problem is when there are data dependency (that CPU cannot overcome) and not enough FMA for the latency to be mitigated. There are 8 FMA here which is quite a lot and this should be enough to mitigate the latency since FMA take AFAIK 4 cycles on Alderlake and 2 can be done per cycle so 8 FMA is optimal (less would cause dependency issues and more would put too much pressure on registers).

"The compiler uses few registers" Not so. I see 12 YMM registers used while AVX2 only provide 16 registers. Only 4 more registers of the ISA are available (that is, not enough to unroll the loop once more). AFAIK, Alderlake does not support AVX-512 (and its 32 registers) anymore (only P-core supported it initially and Intel finally disabled it).

I think low-level profiling using tools like perf or Vtune is critical to understand what is going on in practice and focus on real bottlenecks happening on your specific CPU in real-world conditions (ie. with your specific setup).

@JérômeRichard: Unrolling just barely enough to keep latency x throughput FMAs in flight is often not optimal; any imperfection in uop scheduling misses the chance to start an FMA that cycle for one of the two dep chains that need to start their FMA that cycle.  There's no slack so no room to catch up.  See Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators) for some Skylake experiments.  (Also a more detailed explanation of why reg renaming hides write-after-writ

I finally understand what's going on: The data size I used in the example above is larger than the cache of my computer. The relationship between kb in the two input vectors and the GLOPS/sec is:
| Operation   | GFLOPS/Sec       |
|-------------|------------------|
| FMADD/12    | 127.004/s        |
| FMADD/24    | 123.528/s        |
| FMADD/32    | 124.203/s        |
| FMADD/48    | 125.133/s        |
| FMADD/56    | 125.023/s        |
| FMADD/128   | 109.202/s        |
| FMADD/256   | 91.519/s         |
| FMADD/1024  | 86.1444/s        |
| FMADD/2048  | 85.9394/s        |
| FMADD/4096  | 78.2796/s        |
| FMADD/8192  | 53.0381/s        |
| FMADD/16384 | 39.7985/s        |
| FMADD/32768 | 34.2683/s        |

